# Apache: Response code not 2xx (302) response in bench marking

Tags: apache, http-error

What is the meaning of

> WARNING: Response code not 2xx (302)
>   LOG: header received: HTTP/1.1 302

I found that in Apache bench marking.
What does it mean?

Comment: Hi Debasish, we need some more context, where did you encounter this warning?

Comment: 2XX: request was processed, response sent.  302: redirection.  So it was expecting a response, it got a redirection instead.